# What is the slight difference in meaning between "I refuse" and "I'm refusing"?

Tags: difference, present-continuous, present-simple

I'd like to what's the slight difference in meaning between *I refuse* and *I'm refusing*. For example:

> **I refuse** to work this Sunday.
>
> **I'm refusing** to work this Sunday.

I'm aware of the difference between the present simple and present continuous. But, in this case because of the use of the verb *refuse* and the context, the difference isn't clear to me at all.

I've looked into the subtle differences between the tenses and looked for an answer on the web but  couldn't find anything that answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask yourself what is the difference between "I fish" and "I'm fishing". One is a general, blanket statement; the other refers to a specific ongoing event.

Likewise, "I refuse to work Sundays" would be a blanket refusal - you won't work Sundays, any Sunday. "I'm *refusing* to work Sundays" sounds like you are *currently* refusing to do so. This could imply that it is a temporary situation, or that you are engaged in some currently ongoing argument over the matter.

Of course, your specific example says "*this* Sunday", which limits the reach of either statement. Still, the former sounds more like an immoveable stance, whereas "I'm refusing" sounds like an ongoing discussion which could be subject to change.

Comment: You might say to your supervisor "I refuse to work this Sunday. I notified you weeks ago that it was my grandparents' golden wedding." You might tell a colleague "I'm refusing to work this Sunday. They can't force me to come in."

Comment: Kate, thank you for your comment, but would you please clarify what you mean? Do you mean that "I'm refusing" is used in more informal situations?